# Which web hosting can handle (+1000 clicks per day)?

Tags: web-hosting, shared-hosting, web-traffic

I'm working on a site on which i'll start the marketing campaign in two weeks from now, so i have some concerns with my current hosting **EasyWP (Namecheap)**, it seems they are low in performance with a lot of limitations to their users.

For that reason, I'm considering migrating to another web hosting. I want my website to be ready for **moderate traffic (+1000 click per day)**

For those who are experienced and sure on this matter, I would to know your experts' opinion, i'm considering HostGator Shared hosting will it be enough?

I'd love to know your suggestions on this matter. Thank you in advance for your valuable insights.

Comment: This question will be closed for sure.  But as a rule of thumb, you will get what you pay for.

Comment: Thank you, but could you be any more specific?

Comment: 1000 clicks per day is an average of less than one click per minute. Even if you factor in peak traffic being much higher than average traffic, any decent low-powered server should be able to handle this if configured correctly.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister has explained a bit, but if you buy hosting that costs $1 a month you can be pretty sure that it is going to be a low powered over-crowded server with limited resources.  On the other hand if you get yourself a VPS and pay $30 per month it likely that the server will perform much better...and if you need it, a dedicated server for hundreds of dollars a month will likely be even better.  But it all depends on your needs.

Comment: Yes,i agree, this makes a lot of sense. YOu get what you pay for. Thank you very much, i'll keep that in mind!